# h2o as.h2o(data.frame) Error: Cannot determine file type

Tags: r, rstudio, h2o

I have got a data frame of 15458 objects and 113 variables. I want to convert this to a h2o object with as.h2o(). But i get following error:

```
> data.h2o <- as.h2o(data.model)

ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 500 Internal Server Error (url = http://127.0.0.1:54321/3/ParseSetup)

java.lang.RuntimeException
 [1] "water.MRTask.getResult(MRTask.java:489)"                           "water.MRTask.doAll(MRTask.java:400)"                              
 [3] "water.parser.ParseSetup.guessSetup(ParseSetup.java:211)"           "water.api.ParseSetupHandler.guessSetup(ParseSetupHandler.java:29)"
 [5] "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"       "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)"      
 [7] "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)"   "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"                  
 [9] "water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:56)"                         "water.api.RequestServer.handle(RequestServer.java:676)"           
[11] "water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:613)"             "water.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.run(NanoHTTPD.java:437)"              
[13] "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"                             

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(conn = conn, h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion,  : 
  water.DException$DistributedException: from /127.0.0.1:54321; by class water.parser.ParseSetup$GuessSetupTsk; class water.exceptions.H2OParseSetupException: Problem parsing C:/Users/[...]/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpieIjLY/file25904ef1231d.csv_2
Cannot determine file type.
```

Of course csv_2 is not a valid file type. But i cant't influence the file generation.

Converting a small test dataframe works.

Any ideas?

Comment: I detest when there is a downvote without a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like non ASCII values in the colnames where the problem.

```
#clean colnames
colnames(data.model) <- iconv(colnames(data.model), to='ASCII', sub='')
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar problem with reading a csv file. I traced the problem to a column named as **July4th**. I guess h2o didn't like a column name with a number buried in the middle. Renaming it to July4 worked.